# date picker icon not displayed in the date input field django admin page

Tags: python, django, datepicker, django-admin

I'm currently working on customizing my Django admin page, and I'm facing an issue where the date picker icon is not displayed in the date input field.

[image]

```
class FactureAdmin(ImportExportMixin,admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (AllocationFactureInline,)


admin.site.register(Facture,FactureAdmin)
```

I was expecting to see a date picker with icons to choose the date, similar to this example:

[image]

Additionally, my browser's console is reporting the following error:

[image]

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? The [`DateTimeShortcuts.js` script for the current LTS version, 4.2](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.2/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js#L408) only has 408 lines. Yet your browser says the error occurred at line 429, which doesn't exist. Also, there is no reference to an `addEvent` function anywhere in this script. It calls `window.addEventListener`, though. This makes me wonder if your JS script has been altered, or if your version of Django is out of date.

Comment: Thank you , I think you are right about that JS scripts have been altered